# Newbie SSRS install - logon question

Tags: ssrs-2008

I installed SQL Server Express 2008 with Advanced Services on a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 Standalone.
I am setting up the Reporting Services with Reporting Services Config. Manager.
As far as I can tell, all goes well during installation.
When I surf to the web services URL, http://localhost/ReportServer, I am presented with an username/password dialog.
I've tried all of the logins that I know about on my box, but nothing works.
I tried my logon, the one I use to log onto the server, and I have tried "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" (I left the password blank for this, because I do not know what it is).
When using my server log on username, I also tried to preface it with my machines name, "foo\My Name" (am i correct that the machine name is the default domain name in the case of a box not in a domain?).

Any ideas, or is this not enough info?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the user has to be a SQL Server user.

Comment: I don't believe that's so. At least it's not that way in my domain install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Authentication section of the Directory Security tab of the ReportServer virtual directory in your localhost IIS manager snap-in.  It should probably be set for Integrated Authentication for best security, and that might resolve you permissions problems.